# linq query to select record having same name but different value in two columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dto

I need to fetch the database records into side by side text field.
Here I attached the image of a sample database. This is the image of sample database:

[image]

And I need those results in this image format:
[image]

I tried with these query, but it won't worked for me:

```
var result = await (from d in _dbContext.names
                                  group d.Name by d.Name into g
                                  where g.Count() > 1
                                  select new  CompareNameDto )
```

Can anyone give an example .net code for this problem?

Comment: 'can anyone give the sample'...how about no?

Comment: pic 2 is not clear, can you fill with sample data from pic 1?

Answer (score 0):

you need to populate your new object, right now you are just selecting empty objects

```
var result = await (from d in _dbContext.names
                                  group d.Name by d.Name into g
                                  where g.Count() > 1
                                  select new  CompareNameDto 
                                  {
                                      Id = d.Id,
                                      Name = d.Name,
                                      Weight = d.Weight
                                  })
```